# variable "explicit package name" problems

Tags: perl, variables, compilation, symbols

Ok, I know that this would appear to be a common problem for people coming from other languages - in my case C/C++ and PHP.
However, after having researched and checked and double checked, my frustration has got the better of me.

I am using -

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use vars qw($VERSION @ISA @EXPORT @EXPORT_OK %EXPORT_TAGS);
```

Here is the sub function where the errors arrise -

```
#
# function MergePolygonCircle
#
# parameters
#   Polygon - 2 dimensional array reference
#   Circle - 2 dimensional array reference
#   CircleCenter - array
#   Radius - circle radius float
#
# returns - nuthin
#
sub MergePolygonCircle
{
    my ($Polygon, $Circle, $CircleCenter, $Radius) = @_;
    my $BuffIndex = 0;
    my $SegIndex = 0;
    my $FirstBuffIndex = -1;
    my $FirstCircIndex = -1;
    my $EndBuffIndex = -1;
    my $EndCircIndex = -1;
    my $PolygonLength = @$Polygon; # de-referencing the polygon array to get its size
    my $CircleLength = @$Circle;

    # check to see if the center point of the circle is inside the polygon
    if(GetDistance(@$Polygon[0][0], @$Polygon[0][1], @$CircleCenter[0], @$Ci   rcleCenter[1]) <= $Radius)
    {
        # at this point, the opposite side can only be outside of this circle
        my $Offset = ceil($PolygonLength / 2)-1;

        # remove the end point
        my $EndPoint = pop(@$Polygon);
        # extract the section before the offset
        my $Points = splice(@$Polygon, 0, $Offset);
        # put the points back at the beginning
        splice(@$Polygon, $PolygonLength - $Offset - 1, 0, @$Points);

        # reapply the end point
        push(@$Polygon, @$Polygon[0]);
    }

    # Find the start and end intersections
    for($BuffIndex = 0; $BuffIndex < $PolygonLength-1; $BuffIndex++)
    {
        for($SegIndex = 0; $SegIndex < $CircleLength-1; $SegIndex++)
        {
            if(SegmentsIntersect(@$Polygon[$BuffIndex][0], @$Po   lygon[$BuffIndex][1], @$Polygon[$BuffIndex+1][0], @$Polygon[$BuffIndex+1][1],
                            @$Circle[$SegIndex][0], @$Circle[$SegIndex][1], @$Circle[$SegIndex+1][0], @$Circle[$SegIndex+1][1]))
            {
                if($FirstBuffIndex == -1)
                {
                    $FirstBuffIndex = $BuffIndex;
                    $FirstCircIndex = $SegIndex;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    if($SegIndex != $FirstCircIndex)
                    {
                        $EndBuffIndex = $BuffIndex;
                        $EndCircIndex = $SegIndex;
                    }
                }
            }

            if($FirstBuffIndex > -1 && $EndBuffIndex > -1) break;
        }
        if($FirstBuffIndex > -1 && $EndBuffIndex > -1) break;
    }

    if($FirstBuffIndex > -1 && $EndBuffIndex > -1 && $FirstCircIndex > -1 && $End   CircIndex > -1)
    {
        $FirstBuffIndex++;
        $EndBuffIndex++;
        $FirstCircIndex++;
        if($FirstCircIndex < $EndCircIndex) $EndCircIndex++;

        # remove redundant segments in the main buffer
        splice(@$Polygon, $FirstBuffIndex, ($EndBuffIndex - $FirstBuffIndex));
        # insert the new segments
        if($FirstCircIndex < $EndCircIndex)
        {
            # remove the tail
            $Tail = splice(@$Polygon, $FirstBuffIndex);
            # re-join here
            push(@$Polygon,
                splice(@$PolyCircle, $FirstCircIndex, $EndCircIndex - $FirstCircIndex)),
                @$Tail);
        }
        if($EndCircIndex < $FirstCircIndex)
        {
            # remove the tail
            $Tail = splice(@$Polygon, $FirstBuffIndex);
            $CircTop = splice(@$PolyCircle, $FirstCircIndex);
            $CircTail = splice(@$PolyCircle, 0, $EndCircIndex);
            # stitch them all together
            push(@$Polygon, @$CircTop, @$CircTail, @$Tail);
        }
    }
};
```

I am getting errors such as -

```
"my" variable $PolygonLength masks earlier declaration in same scope
Global symbol "$BuffIndex" requires explicit package name
Global symbol "$PolygonLength" requires explicit package name
Global symbol "$SegIndex" requires explicit package name
Global symbol "$CircleLength" requires explicit package name
Global symbol "$Polygon" requires explicit package name
```

I cannot see where these errors are coming from.  I realise that this is a bit long, but in my last question I was asked for "real" code ...

### Update

Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am using version 5.12.3 through CGI (apache under windows)

Comment: You don't show where `$PolygonLength` is being declared the first time (probably as a global somewhere), and it's hard to debug the other errors without line number references to the code; you're trying to access those variables somewhere that's out of scope, probably not in the code you've shared.

Comment: @Woobie - the variable `$PolygonLength` is the 8th variable declaration at the top of the sub.  In addition, I stated that all of the errors raised are located within this block. This is the only area where the variables occur and as the file is 310 lines long, it would be unreasonable to include all of the file just to prove what I am saying.

Answer (score 1):

This line has syntax errors:

```
if(GetDistance(@$Polygon[0][0], @$Polygon[0][1], @$CircleCenter[0], @$Ci   rcleCenter[1]) <= $Radius)
```

If `$Polygon` is a reference to a two-dimensional array you should use `$Polygon->[0][0]` or `${$Polygon}[0][0]`. See [perldoc perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References).

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you write too much C code :-)

if statements in Perl *require* a block.

"break" in C is spelled "last" in Perl.

```
if($FirstBuffIndex > -1 && $EndBuffIndex > -1) {last};
```

Also,

```
@$Polygon[0][0]
```

isn't going to work, you probably want

```
$Polygon->[0][0]
```

Comment: and "continue" is spelled `next`

Comment: return value of `splice` is a list:
`$Tail = splice(@$Polygon,$FirstBuffIndex)` ought to be `@Tail = splice(@$Polygon, $FirstBuffIndex)`.